# Call a function from within the script from the html page with an extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, referenceerror

I have a script (For the purposes of this question: `script.js`) that is injected into every page (along with `jquery.js`).
`script.js` is supposed to add an extra element(`elem`) to the page, which when clicked, invokes a `my_func` inside `script.js`.

The trouble is that there is always a `ReferenceError: my_func is not defined`, when the element is clicked, but it is defined in `script.js`. I realized it has something to do with the "isolated environment" thing.. but I don't know how to solve this problem..

PS.: New to Chrome, JS and JQuery.
<sub>History: Python :)</sub>

---

Some code (Just the adding of the elem):

```
function on_ready(){
    var wanted = get_desired() // fetch desirable elements
    add_to_all(wanted) // this calls add for every element in wanted
}
function add(obj_to_edit) {
    if (obj_to_edit.css('position') == 'static'){
        obj_to_edit.css('position','relative')}

    var elem = $("<div ... onclick='my_func(this)'>...</div>")

    obj_to_edit.mouseenter(show_button);
    obj_to_edit.mouseleave(hide_button);
    elem.prependTo(obj_to_edit);
    elem.hide()
}

function my_func(elem){
    console.log($(elem).parent().html)
}

$(document).ready(on_ready);
```

The idea is when someone hovers over a certain object, `elem` pops up, and when the user clicks it, it logs a message..

Comment: do you have the `my_func` inside the document ready function. Also ensure that the `script.js` comes after `jquery.js`.

Comment: @saravanan Yes.. I have a function that sets up every-thing, and it's in `$(document).ready(...)`. Yes it does..

Comment: If you are using an inline `onclick` try changing it to be defined in your script instead.

Comment: @BeardFist Actually the call is `my_func(this)`, so that I get the element, as I might have injected multiple for those "elements".

Comment: You need to post a simple example of your code that demonstrates the problem. We aren't mind readers, we can't tell what you did wrong without seeing the code, and trying to divine it with question/answer like this will be frustrating.

Comment: @Barmar That's fine. Added (some) code. *We aren't mind readers*, I know that! :) Nor, am I..

Comment: Is that function definition inside the `$(document).ready(...)`?

Comment: @Barmar No .. Wait, i'll post some more code and info..

Comment: Can you give it a try by moving the `my_func` in the script outside the `$(document).ready(....)` and post the update. This should work because the function will be available even after the document is loaded so that the elements can make use of.

Comment: @saravanan It is outside. see my edit..

Comment: @Schoolboy: Please try to move the `my_func` as the first method or try to use the live method of binding eventhandlers to elements. Also please inspect the script file in the browser also and try to invoke it from the chrome developer tool console.

Comment: None of your edits show how `my_func()` is defined.

Comment: @Barmar It isn't something great, it's just an printing function at the moment...

Comment: I don't care about the definition, I care about HOW you're defining it. Are you defining it inside the `ready()` handler? That will put the function definition inside a local scope, so it can't be accessed from the global scope of `onclick` tags. The function has to be defined in the global scope.

Comment: @Barmar The program structure is just like that, it's outside the ready(). It is global..

Comment: Please do not use the term "injected" for the normal inclusion of a script using a `script` tag. "Injected" as a particular meaning related to dynamic insertion of the script at run time via code, and using it incorrectly could (at least temporarily) confuse some readers.

Comment: What do you mean by "the isolated environment thing"??

Answer (score 0):

The first question is why you're doing this. Sorry, you do need to answer that if you want people to really help you with anything beyond purely mechanical issues.

For instance, depending on what you're doing, you could be much better off by using a `::before` pseudo-element whose visibility responds to the `hover` state:

```
.desired::before {
    content: "Press me!";
    display: none;
}
.desired::before:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

That's it--no insertions, no mouseenter or mouseleave events, just pure CSS.

In terms of setting the event handler, it's a bit odd that you're using the old-style `onclick` attribute, where the modern approach, of course, would be

```
elem.on("click",function(){...});
```

Or, a bit more cleanly

```
elem.on("click",my_func);
```

where my_func is rewritten with `this` as the element in question:

```
function my_func(){
    console.log($(this).parent().html);
}
```

I'm not getting what you are trying to accomplish by changing the value of the `position` CSS property to `relative`. This will have no effect unless you're also specifying properties such as `top`. By the way, the check for a `position` of `static` will probalby not do what you want--this check will succeed only if the element in question has an explicit position of static, either by being specified in a `style` attribute or being set previously by a `.css` call. Therefore, your change of property value to `relative` will probably never happen.

In any case, if for some reason the original HTML does not have this, and you really want to add it dynamically, it's a lot cleaner to just add a class to the desired elements and then using CSS rules to set `position` and whatever other properties you want to change, compared to going around twiddling with the CSS on every single element. That's what classes and CSS rules are for:

```
get_desired().addClass("desired");
```

assuming `get_desired` returns a jQuery DOM collection. If you're an aficionado of the chained style, you can set the event handler here too with

```
get_desired().addClass("desired").on("click",my_func);
```

Then, just

```
.desired {
    position: relative;
}
```

As for the specific issue you're raising, if your code is actually as you are showing it, then of course `my_func` should be found. So something else is going on. The only way to have people here help you track down the problem is to show ALL the code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting `ReferenceError: my_func is not defined`, as you guessed, has to do with the *"isolated environment" thing*. `onclick` handlers defined in html properties run in the normal page context, while your function is defined in the content script context.

The solution to *that* problem is to add the click handler programmatically, which is better practice anyway. Just remove `onclick='my_func(this)'` from your html string and add the following line:

```
elem.click( my_func );
```

For other considerations, see torazaburo's answer.